# TypeError: loadCorpus() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
#done reading all word types
#read all the training sentences

sent= loadCorpus('bangla-corpuscleaned.txt','UTF-8')
print (sent[0][0])
print ('done reading corpus')
print (len(types))
types = []
```

Comment: You're passing in two arguments to a function that takes one

Comment: What is the NLP library you're using? Read the documentation of its `loadCorpus` function to find the correct way to use it.

Comment: i'm using NLTK.

Comment: @Sayse i know that sir but can't solve this problem

Comment: You're better off looking in the documentation for `loadCorpus` and NLTK and figuring out what parameters it does accept.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NLTK, but I've been trying to find the `loadCorpus` function by googling with no success. Is that a library function or one that you defined?

Comment: Thank you all i'd solve this problem